# Delete the folder the executing batch-script lies in

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a win-cmd-script "a" saved in folder "f", and want to delete the folder "f" with the script itself. Is that possible, and if yes, how?

I know, that a batch-file can delete itself:

```
(goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"
```

And now I have tried:

```
set mypath=%~dp0

rmdir %mypath%
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: If any application has the folder open, like Windows Explorer or any application has an open file handle on a file in that directory it is not going to delete.  So this would include if the working directory of the batch file is the folder you want to delete.  So at a minimum you would need to do a change directory to get out of that folder structure in the batch file. Not sure how you are going to check for any other applications having that folder open.

Comment: Its a sort of self deleting installer file. Once its done, its gone.

Comment: So just as a test. I created a single folder and created a batch file in it.  In the batch file I had two commands. 1) `cd ..` 2) `rmdir /s /q "%~dp0"`.  I executed this from the command prompt and was in that folder when I executed it.  It did delete the directory.

Comment: I did exactly the same. But on my system it only deleted the file?! weird..

Comment: `pushd "%temp%" && rmdir /Q/S "%~dp0"` That will simply change the working directory, then remove the folder.

Comment: @Gerhard, why filling the `pushd` stack without using `popd` to clean up, why not using `cd /D`?

Comment: @aschipfl `popd` will fail because the `dir` no longer exists. If the purpose of the line is to "cleanup" it will simply exit after completion. In otherwords, once exited the stored `pushd` no longer exists, so `popd` should not be relevant. so either `pushd` and `cd /d` should be fine as `errorlevel` will be 0 either way.

Comment: @Gerhard, I agree, surely `popd` cannot change back. But `pushd` writes the previous directory into a stack, which remains even when the directory becomes deleted later. Only `popd` can delete this stack entry (what it does even when the stored directory does no longer exist; `popd` will then just stick at the current directory without setting `ErrorLevel`). In most situations, this stack residue may be irrelevant though…

Comment: but the memory is cleared on exit, @aschipfl, is it not? We can test this. open `cmd` and run `powershell` from it, then `pushd %temp%` followed by `Get-Location -stack`, then exit `powershell` back into `cmd` and run `powershell Get-Location -stack` again.

Comment: Yes, @Gerhard, the stack is discarded as soon as the `cmd.exe` instance is terminated.

Comment: So we are good then with `pushd`, @aschipfl? `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a folder if any process has the folder as the active folder.  If you want to remove it, you need to ensure the cmd process executing the script has moved to a different folder:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set path_to_del=%~dp0
cd /d %USERPROFILE%
rmdir /s/q "%path_to_del%"
```

This will remove the folder containing the script, though, it will error out as it attempts to scan the file for the line after the `rmdir` call.  Also, if you have any other tools open in this folder, such as notepad, then the directory will remain.

Comment: 5 lines to delete a folder? You don't need to `set` variables at all. This will do the same. `pushd "%temp%" && rmdir /Q/S "%~dp0"`

Comment: Sure, I'd rather be verbose when describing something, but you could do this in a single line if you prefer